# How to use document.getelement by id for arrays which are locted in another array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web-applications, javascript-objects

Sample code.

```
<script>
  var app = (function () {
    var config = {
      X:345,
      Y:543,
      Z: [
        [1,3],
        [2,4],
        [3,6]
      ]
    };
  }());
</script>
```

Here I want to pass values into **Z dynamically** from **input field**. How can i do it? How to access such kind of an object from html using onclick event.
please provide any fiddle example or sample html and js code if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Add an event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an example where values are added to `Z` based on what you type in an input field. I hope this answers your question, if anything is unclear just ask.

```js
var app = (function () {
  var config = {
    X:345,
    Y:543,
    Z: [
      [1,3],
      [2,4],
      [3,6]
    ]
  };
  
  function onFormSubmitted(event) {
    // Prevent the browser from actually submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const
      input = document.getElementById('input');
    // Make sure the input was found and it has a value in it.
    if (input === null || input.value === '') {
      return;
    }
    
    // Push the value in the input into Z.
    config.Z.push(input.value);
    // Reset the form.
    event.target.reset();
  }

  function logConfig() {
    console.log(config);
  }

  function init() {
    const 
      form = document.getElementById('form');
      
    if (form !== null) {
      // Listen for the submit event to add the value in the input to Z.
      form.addEventListener('submit', onFormSubmitted);
    }
  }
  
  
  init();
  
  // Return the logConfig method so it can be called from outside.
  return {
    logConfig
  }
}());

const
  logButton = document.getElementById('log');
// Whenever the log button is clicked, log the current app config.  
logButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  app.logConfig();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="number" id="input"/>
  <button>Add number</button>
</form>

<button id="log" type="button">log config</button>
```